# Week type in different countries

Tags: android, calendar

There are some countries which first day of week begin on Sunday, instead other countries like mine begin on Monday. Is there any way to know which calendar is used in the country of the user.

I'm developing an application in Android with a calendar and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: try [`Calendar.getInstance(someLocale).getFirstDayOfWeek()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek%28%29).

Comment: It works great :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set your country timeZone in Calendar class.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
cal.setTimeZone(tz);
```

or

you can add the offset by if using UTC date or time.